# Corda Accounts Functionality Doubts

Tags: corda

I am trying to integrate Accounts Functionality in my CordApp, and was going through the supply chain demo https://github.com/corda/accounts-demo-supplychain

Here is a list of my queries:

1. What is the purpose of the Account Broadcast flow?, not mentioned in the readme file https://github.com/corda/accounts-demo-supplychain/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/accounts_SupplyChain/flows/AccountBroadcast.kt
2. Is the purpose of Share Account Flow, only that the counter party node's know's the account identity, what if I don't want to use it?
3. Since account is a sub-vault of the node's vault, that data is visible to that node right?

Answer (score 2):

1. To share account infos with other nodes on in the zone. You need to do this so that they know which node and account belongs to.
2. Same as above. You don't have to use it.
3. Yes.

Comment: is there an example where this flow is called since it's not called here? https://github.com/corda/accounts-demo-supplychain/blob/master/workflows/src/main/kotlin/com/accounts_SupplyChain/flows/AccountBroadcast.kt